# Magento 2 - Open dropdown on mouse hover

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, php, javascript

How can I make the dropdown **Sort By** to open on when putting the mouse over it instead click on it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to triggering click events not usually working for this and there being cross browser issues I would recommend using 'fake' dropdowns. There are plugins that make this very easy and have the added benefit of being easily styling.

One example is http://selectric.js.org/demo.html, you can then just add the class `selectric-open` on hover which would open the dropdown.

[image]

I know this doesn't directly solve the issue with the default OS dropdown but it may prove useful for some people.

Comment: It's mad how much of a pain this is to actually do. I would of thought a simulated click would suffice.

Comment: thank you ben for your answer, so is the only way? we can't do that hover with magento default?

Comment: It is possible without using a third party, you could add a `size` attribute and a height to it, although you'll need to do quite a bit more work as it breaks the styling on other elements. To see this in action run the following in your console: `var $ = jQuery;` and then `$('#sorter').attr('size', 6).css('height', '300px');`. I can't say for sure these are the only methods as I haven't done this in the past but I'll be surprised if there's an easy to do it and keep native dropdowns. Browsers are quite protective of native some native inputs.